# Using std::visit with variadic template struct

Tags: c++, c++17

I was trying to understand the following example which I got from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>


using var_t = std::variant<int, long, double, std::string>;

template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
// what is this declaration imply???
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

int main() {
    std::vector<var_t> vec = {10, 15l, 1.5, "hello"};


    for (auto& v: vec) {
        std::visit(overloaded {
            [](auto arg) { std::cout << arg << '\n'; },
            [](double arg) { std::cout << std::fixed << arg << '\n'; },
            [](const std::string& arg) { std::cout << std::quoted(arg) << '\n'; },
        }, v);
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain how this overloaded struct works? Especially what I didn't understand is the following declaration.

```
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
```

Without this declaration, the compiler issues the following error messages.

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:26:9: error: class template argument deduction failed:
         }, v);
         ^
main.cpp:26: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

Purpose: learning

Comment: There is [a proposal](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0051r2.pdf) to add something like that to the standard library as `std::overload`, and [a 5-minute video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gNzhE-Tn40&list=PLs3KjaCtOwSZ2tbuV1hx8Xz-rFZTan2J1&index=50) about implementing this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can someone please explain how this overloaded struct works? Especially what I didn't understand is the following declaration.
>
> ```
> template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
> ```

That's an [user-defined deduction guide](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.guide#nt:deduction-guide) (link to the working draft).
It's a feature of the language introduced by the latest revision of the standard along with class template arguments deduction. See also [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) for more details and a more user-friendly explanation.
This is not a proper explanation, but for the sake of simplicity you can consider it as an *hint* you can give to lead the deduction of the template arguments out of a set of parameters given to the constructor.

---

As a side note, [here](https://github.com/tvaneerd/cpp17_in_TTs/blob/master/ALL_IN_ONE.md) I found an example that is pretty clear and it's worth copying it over:

```
template<typename T>
struct Thingy { T t; };

Thingy(const char *) -> Thingy<std::string>;

// ...

Thingy thing{"A String"}; // thing.t is a `std::string`.
```

Credits are for @NicolBolas, an active user here on SO. Unfortunately I can't find the answer from which this example has been taken.

Comment: @PaulVarghese You are welcome. That's how SO works: one open a question, someone else does his best trying to reply. Hope this answer can help you and future readers.

Comment: It should be noted that `overload` works because aggregate initialization in C++17 was extended to be able to initialize base class subobjects as well as members. Also, it's "Nicol Bolas", [the Tyrant of Worlds](http://magic.wizards.com/en/story/planeswalkers/nicol-bolas), not Nicolas.

Comment: @NicolBolas You are absolutely right. My fault. I'm fixing the name immediately. Can I copy and paste the rest of the comment as it is?