# Variant: no matching function for call to 'get'

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17, variant

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    virtual void Foo() = 0;    
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void Foo() override {
        std::cout << "B::Foo()" << std::endl;   
    }
};

class C :public A {
public:
    void Foo() override {
        std::cout << "C::Foo()" << std::endl;   
    }
};

template<typename... Args>
class D {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void Foo() {
        m_variant = T{};
    }

    void Bar() {
      std::get<m_variant.index()>(m_variant).Foo();
    }

private:
    std::variant<std::monostate, Args...> m_variant;
};

int main() {
    D<B, C> d;
    d.Foo<B>();
    d.Bar();

    d.Foo<C>();
    d.Bar();
}
```

(c.f [wandbox.org](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mrryDZ4i7JWWdlCn))

I'm getting the error `no matching function for call to 'get'` but I don't figure out why. `std::variant::index()` is constexpr, so it isn't the problem (I tested by putting directly the value `1`, but still the same error).
I have a `std::monostate` to prevent an empty variant (when no args are in `typename... Args`)

Comment: `m_variant.index()` is a runtime value, use visitor instead (`std::visit([](auto& e) { e.Foo(); }, m_variant);`).

Comment: While it's true that the [`index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/index) function is marked `constexpr`, the variable `m_variant` is *not* and can therefore not be used at compile-time.

Comment: The result of `std::variant::index()` is a constant expression only if the variant object it's called on is a constant expression. Yours isn't.

Comment: Oww, yeah, didn't know that, thank you ! So I use `std::visit` instead

Comment: BTW, if you use only polymorphism class, you might use (smart) pointer on base class instead of `variant`.

Comment: In my real code, I have some member variables that couldn't be in the base class, so I have to store the real object not to have slicing problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`m_variant.index()` is a runtime value (as `m_variant` is not a constant expression).

The way to dispatch is to use visitor, as:

```
std::visit([](auto& v) { v.Foo(); }, m_variant);
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UTQnCVMmyFcdVQqS)

Comment: Could you please shortly explain how `overloaded` works? I've seen [std::visit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) docs, but it is not explained there.

Comment: It allows to group several functors with `operator ()`. That allows to build at call site with lambda instead of writing a dedicated functor with all the overload for `operator()`.

Comment: @AMA - See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020573/using-stdvisit-with-variadic-template-struct/45020724#45020724) for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Something marked `constexpr` tells you that in certain situations it can be called at compile time.  It does *not* guarantee it can always be called at compile time.

I the case of `variant`, `index` can be called at compile time *if the variant itself is a constexpr value*.  Otherwise it is a runtime method.

You can either read documentation about when something can be called at compile time, or reason about it; in this case, if the type of variant could vary at runtime, how can `index` be a compile time constant?  Remember that only the ttpe and constexpr ness of values, plus if itself is in a compile time context, can be used to reason about "can this be called at compile time".